# How to set scroll policy to HScrollBar (auto visible)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I added an extra horizontal scroll bar to spark DataGrid skin.

```
<!-- column header, content -->
<s:VGroup horizontalAlign="justify" gap="0" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:GridColumnHeaderGroup .... />
    <s:Group height="100%">
        <!-- header separator, scroller and grid -->
        <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="justify" height="100%" width="100%" gap="-1">
            <s:Line id="headerSeparator"/>
            <s:Scroller id="scroller"  minViewportInset="1" hasFocusableChildren="false" 
                    height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                    // turned off horizontal scroll policy
                <s:Grid id="grid">....</s:Grid>
            </s:Scroller>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Group>
    <ferp:GridColumnFooterGroup /> // my footer group component 
    <s:HScrollBar id="hScrollBar" viewport="{grid}"     
             width="{grid.width}" />                 
</s:VGroup>
```

It works fine, but HScrollBar always visible and included in layout.
How to make HScrollBar visible and included only when needed (similar to horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" in Scroller component)?

Comment: I think you're going to have to share your whole custom skin before we can offer assistance. But, most likely you're going to have write ActionScript code to hide/display the scrollbar based on whether it is needed or not; and then to layout the other components based on whether the scrollbar is displayed or not.

Comment: It is standard spark DataGrid skin where i just insert two components:  GridColumnFooterGroup (modified HeaderGroup) and Horizontal scroller, and set horizontalScrollPolicy to off in existing Scroller component.

Comment: There is some progress. I've created custom skin for HScrollBar, where i added  `visible.inactive="false" includeInLayout.inactive="false"` to existing skin.<br>Result: HScrollBar appears and dissapears when needed, but still included in layout. I thing dataGrid skin not detecting this.